# Cells formatting works only on visible (not filtered) rows

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-sheets

I'm working with GDrive Spreadsheets and Google App Script. I need to change the format and background colour for all the cells, and I need to do it programmatically. The following code works great:

```
ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).setNumberFormat("@STRING@").setBackground("cyan");
```

the only problem is that it works **only** on the visible rows/columns - i.e. if you filter your sheet on a particular column value, the code above will work only on the currently shown rows.

For example, I have the following spreadsheet

[image]

I proceed with adding a filter on the 2nd column:

[image]

as you can see I choosed to filter the 2nd column on **zxc** value. Now I need to format the spreadsheet's cells with a cyan background, using google app script. Here's the code:

```
function testFormat(){
  var id = "theIdOfMySpreadsheet";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var ss = sheet.getSheets()[0];
  ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, ss.getLastColumn()).setBackground("cyan");
}
```

and here's the result on the spreadsheet:

[image]

Everything seems to be fine. But look what happens if I remove the filter:

[image]

only 2 rows out of 5 have the right background colour, even if I have set it on the **whole** range. I have already tested the length of the returned range, and it works fine as it returns 5 rows and 3 columns.

Has any of you ever faced this issue? How can I force it to change the background also on the filtered out rows?

Answer (score 0):

If there was an Apps Script method for the equivalent of **Data** - **Turn Off Filter**, then you could clear the hidden rows.  But as of this moment, that possibility doesn't exist.

One option is to highlight the entire range **first**, with all the data, before any filter has been applied.  When the range is filtered to a smaller list, the color formatting will only be on the smaller list.  When it's put back, it will return to the whole list.

You are filtering first, then applying the background.  Try applying the background color first.

If you can't do that, then you can use an installable `onChange` trigger to monitor for the OTHER event type.  The OTHER event type is triggered by a data filter, and other events.

But you'd need to know the state before and after the filter.  So you'd need to somehow record the original state, and then check for a change, like number of rows displayed.

Comment: what I need is to deacrivate programmatically the sheet filters before I proceed with the gas script, I need to do it by code as I can't remove the filters manually. I don't think this is possible anyway, the class current api does not provide any kind of function that allow this unfortunately :( thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background color on all the rows, why not change the color first and then apply the filters ? (Note: My reputation does not allow me to comment, so I am posting this as answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote to get around this problem. 
It checks for a filter on the worksheet and inactivates any filter criteria present on a column, sets the background color on the specified ranges and then re-activates the filter criteria.

```js
// Globals
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var SH = SS.getSheetByName('Data');

var COLOR = {
  draft: '#d9ead3', // light green
  published: '#93c47d' // dark green
};

function colorBg_(sheet, a1Notations, color) {
  // color must be null to reset
  // calling the .setBackground method with undefined does nothing 
  // and with no argument throws an error
  color = color? color: null;

  // calling .getRangeList with wrapping a1Notation strings in an array throws an error
  a1Notations = !Array.isArray(a1Notations)? [a1Notations]: a1Notations;

  const filter = sheet.getFilter(); // returns null if there is no filter present (does not throw error)
  if (!filter) { // no filter, no problems

    // this works fine even with a single range in the list
    sheet.getRangeList(a1Notations).setBackground(COLOR.published);

  } else { // temporary remove filters so color will be applied to all visible rows

    const headerColumns = filter.getRange().getValues()[0];

    const filterCriterias = headerColumns.reduce(function(criterias, column, index) {
      const columnPosition = index + 1;
      const criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition);
      if (criteria) {
        criterias[columnPosition] = criteria;
      }
      return criterias;
    }, {});

    const filteredColumnPositions = Object.keys(filterCriterias);

    filteredColumnPositions.forEach(function(columnPosition) {
    // const columnPosition = parseInt(key, 10); // this step is unnecessary, 
    // columnPosition can be a number or a string
      filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition);
    });

    // now that filters are inactive and all rows are visible, set the color
    sheet.getRangeList(a1Notations).setBackground(color);

    // replace filter criteria on columns
    filteredColumnPositions.forEach(function(columnPosition) {
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriterias[columnPosition]);
    });
  }
}

function colorDefault (color) {
  const a1Notation = 'E2:F';
  colorBg_(SH, a1Notation) // colorBg_ function will default color argument to null
}

function colorPublished () {
  var a1Notations = [
    'E3:F6',
    'F8',
    'E10'
  ];
  colorBg_(SH, a1Notations, COLOR.published);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Enter your sheet name in getSheetByName function.

function clearFilter() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssId = ss.getId();
var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
var filter =sheetId.getFilter();

for(var i=1;i<=column.length;i++)//colunm.length means number of columns.
{
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.